# how to pass different parameters to different methods in one statement?

Tags: python

I need to make several requests, using either `get` or `post` method, I want to write the requests into one statement like

```
response = getattr(requests, method)(url, parameters)
```

when `method == 'get'`, Above should work as `response = getattr(requests, method)(url, params=parameters)`, when `method == 'post'`, it should work as `response = getattr(requests, method)(url, json=parameters)`

Comment: You could make a dictionary with properly named keys for each and pass that dictionary as the parameters in the function call depending on variable 'method'. Something like getattr(requests, method)((dict_get if method=="get" else dict_post)).

Comment: Or getattr(requests, method)({"get":dict_get, "post":dict_post}[method]) however the readability suffers when you try to achieve this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rely on destructuring for something that doesn't look too terribly ugly.

```
response = getattr(requests, method)(url, **{('params' if method=='get' else 'json'):parameters})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getattr(method):
    if method == "get": return requests.get
    elif method == "post": return requests.post
```

When you call `getattr(method)` it will return a function object accordingly. Next you can call the returned function object accordingly.

`response = getattr("get")(url, params=parameters)` translates to `response = requests.get(url, params=parameters)`

Answer (score 0):

```
params = xxx
json =yyy

if method == 'GET':
   response = getattr(requests, method)(url, parameters = params)
elif method == 'POST':
   response = getattr(requests, method)(url, parameters = json)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.